# How to know which version of docker image is behind latest tag?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, version

I am working with two docker images of tensorflow (latest and latest-gpu tags):

`FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`

and:

`FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`

In order to not have surprises in the future, I would like to set the version of these two images.

On docker hub, I can't find this information in [the tags pages](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/): for example, `latest` would correspond to the `1.8.0-gpu` tag.

Do you know if and where I can find this information?

Thank you,

Alexandre

Comment: Take a look at this: [The misunderstood Docker tag: latest](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375). It concludes at *"Don’t use it. Don’t be tempted by it. It’s easy to look at it and think that your deployment script should just pull “latest” and your build process will ensure that’s valid. It takes a lot of discipline to make that work. Just version your tags. Every time."*

Comment: I read it already :) I totally agree with him. I now would like to use versioned tags but I can't find what the `latest` tag actually refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know if and where I can find this information?

Just to make something clear. Docker images can have multiple tags around them. Closer inspection of said images reveal that they have single tag only (just `latest`) so they are not tagged additionally. Thus said from images themselves you can't deduct which tensorflow version they relate to.

However, you do have other option:

- Easiest way to make sure you use correct 'versioned' tensorflow image instead of `latest` is to actually start latest image:

  ```
  docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
  ```

  or

  ```
  nvidia-docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
  ```

  then, navigate to given url link in format:

  ```
  http://localhost:8888/?token=XXXX...
  ```

  and in jupyter create new notebook `File->New Noteboot->Python2` and there check tensorflow version by giving:

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf
  print tf.VERSION
  ```

  or

  ```
  import tensorflow as tf
  tf.__version__
  ```

  Then run it. Note that in my case for `latest` tag response was: `1.8.0`, however if you pulled `latest` image a while ago and didn't update in the meantime (or reading this in the future) version you get can be different than this.
- Once you got the version you are using, you can simply navigate at the [the tags pages](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/) you mentioned in your post to take correct tag (in my case that would be `1.8.0` and `1.8.0-gpu` respectively (since I was offered Python2 from `latest` tag).
- Short note on selecting proper tag from suffixes (for 1.8.0 version):

  - In most cases you will select one of the following stable release images:

    - 1.8.0-gpu-py3 - stable release image gpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-py3 - stable release image cpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-gpu - stable release image gpu python 2
    - 1.8.0 - stable release image cpu python 2 <-- this is proper tag in my case for cpu `latest`.
  - However, you might choose development or release candidates in some special circumstances:

    - 1.8.0-devel-gpu-py3 - development release gpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-devel-gpu - development release gpu python 2
    - 1.8.0-devel-py3 - development release cpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-devel - development release cpu python 2
    - 1.8.0-rcN-devel-gpu-py3 - development release candidate gpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-rcN-devel-py3 - development release candidate cpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-rcN-gpu-py3 - stable release candidate gpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-rcN-py3 - stable release candidate cpu python 3
    - 1.8.0-rcN-gpu - stable release candidate gpu python 2
    - 1.8.0-rcN - stable release candidate cpu python 2

Comment: this is a super hyper specific answer to this particular image, wouldn't be better to have shell or python script parse the above said tags _HTML_ page from a CLI to try and determine which version the _latest_ tag corresponds to?

Comment: The question was related to obtaining the info about exact version instead of using latest to set it to fixed value to avoid surprises. If you would extract latest info automatically, then you could use latest tag altogether. Question was not related to automatically monitoring changes in latest (what you propose, and in some cases that can be pretty involved script), but means to determine a correct version to make it fixed instead of simply set to latest (which can and will lead to surprises).

Answer (score 12):

go to image webpage (nigix in my case) https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx
then press tags tab,
go to any latest, and copy sha256 sum
then sort by newest, then scroll down until first numbered version
and check if the exact same sha256 is displayed

now ... **STILL** after that fishing, there library/nginxit comes a sure thing:

you can verify if you did it right, for example now I manage to find that nginx:latest is actually 1.17.8, so, I run:

```
docker pull nginx:1.17.8
1.17.8: Pulling from library/nginx
bc51dd8edc1b: Pull complete
66ba67045f57: Pull complete
bf317aa10aa5: Pull complete
Digest:sha256:ad5552c786f128e389a0263104ae39f3d3c7895579d45ae716f528185b36bc6f
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:1.17.8
```

and then I verify by atempt to pull latest:

```
docker pull nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:ad5552c786f128e389a0263104ae39f3d3c7895579d45ae716f528185b36bc6f
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
```

how you can see it didn't actually pull anything, and sha256 is the exact same ;)